# Strange operator (!) in Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators, prolog-cut

```
hi(g,plus(A,B),int) :- hi(g,A,int),hi(g,B,int),!.
```

in the above statement what does the '!' sign at the end of the statement do ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the [cut operator](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node88.html#sec.l10.cut), which basically states "if we got up to here, don't backtrack."

So, if both recursive calls succeed, the `hi` predicate will not retry them.